# Image loads locally but not when site is live

Tags: html, image

My live site is andreaivy.com/neptune/gallery.html. The last row of images are not rendering but it does on my computer. I have the HTML page in the main directory and the image in a sub-folder called "img." I have tried clearing my cache, using incognito and none of it has worked. I even tried putting an image that renders elsewhere on the site in this code and that doesn't render either. I've validated my code with WC3 Validator and it says the image code is fine. Below is an example of the code for one of the images. What do I need to do to get the image to render?

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
      <img class="img-responsive" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#vid1" src="img/danceimg.png" alt="Flamethrowers dancing to drums." /></div>
```

Comment: Is the path different from your computer to your server?

Comment: What do you see when you try to display the image (when you use the image url)?

Comment: Are your images in `andreaivy.com/img/` or `andreaivy.com/neptune/img/`?

Comment: the path is the same .  the path is andreaivy.com/neptune/img/. the image doesn't show when i use the image url :(. In the server the file looks different than the others, why is that?

Comment: Can you visit the url in your browser and see the images load? Forget loading through the tag, make sure the url works and loads the image. Then figure out what is wrong with the path you are feeding into the image tag.

Comment: @ChipDean it looks like beach.PNG instead of beach.png. When i use the capital in the extension, i can see the image. I'll try adjusting my code.

Comment: @ChipDean it was the capital in the extension. Once I fixed that it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to upload the images to your website server through an FTP or something similar. Be sure to keep the path consistent though.